# Flutter Class Properties (basics)

Tags: flutter, class, properties

How do you pass properties to a widget class in flutter.

Here is a basic class

```
class ToolbarToggle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Text(label);
}}
```

I want to be able to call it

```
ToolbarToggle(label: 'a label')
```

Forgive the elementary question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you declare a label property, like this:

```
class ToolbarToggle extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(label);
  }
}
```

`final` means the value is immutable, you should add it to every property on a StatelessWidget.

Now we need to declare a Constructor, here is how we do that:

```
ToolbarToggle(this.label);
```

This means that when creating a ToolbarToggle, we can do this: `ToolbarToggle('some label');`. In order to make parameters named, we need to declare the constructor like so:

```
ToolbarToggle({this.label});
```

Now it is possible to call `ToolbarToggle(label: 'my label');`. But this will give an error, because it's possible you don't actually pass any value when calling the constructor. To fix this, you should either make it a required parameter, or give it a default value:

```
ToolbarToggle({required this.label});
```

```
ToolbarToggle({this.label=''});
```

Here is the final class code:

```
class ToolbarToggle extends StatelessWidget {
  ToolbarToggle({required this.label});

  final String label;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(label);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class ToolbarToggle extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final String? label;
  
  const ToolbarToggle({this.label, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(label ?? 'label is null');
  }}
```

Like this, you can pass properties,
Its recommended to use `const` constructor and a `key` param ( to uniquely identify incase)

Answer (score 1):

You missed using the `label`

```
class ToolbarToggle extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  ToolbarToggle({required this.label});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text(label);
}}
```

Comment: If you pass Non-Nullable values in the named parameters
You have to put required ,

like this,
 final String label;
 ToolbarToggle({required this.label});